# Converting object attributes to array to HTML using .map()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm creating an object, putting the attributes of that object into an array and then mapping the array to HTML output and I end up with line after line of commas? Where are these commas coming from?

```
let results = []

class Polygon {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "Hexagon"
    this.edges = 6
    this.size = 1
  }
  setName(value) {
    this.name = value
  }
  setEdges(value) {
    this.edges = value
  }
  setSize(value) {
    this.size = value
  }
  getArea() {
    return this.size * this.size
  }
}

let shape = new Polygon()
shape.setName("Square")
shape.setEdges(4)
shape.setSize(6)

results.push(shape.name)
results.push(shape.edges)
results.push(shape.size)
results.push(shape.getArea())

console.log(results)

resultsDiv = document.querySelector('#results')
resultsDiv.innerHTML = results.map(r => '<p>' + r + '</p>')
```

Here's the fiddle with the HTML:
https://jsfiddle.net/ruzel/qyrczkup/3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map` returns another array and when you pass it to `innerHTML`, it becomes a string version of it.

Just try it: `console.log(results.map(r => '<p>' + r + '</p>').toString())`
returns: `<p>Square</p>,<p>4</p>,<p>6</p>,<p>36</p>`

To solve this, just transform that array to a string properly before setting it as HTML:

```
resultsDiv.innerHTML = results.map(r => '<p>' + r + '</p>').join('')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also resolve this with `reduce` and `template string` since map returns an array and InnerHTML does `toString` on the array:

```
resultsDiv.innerHTML = results.reduce((r,c) => r.concat(`<p>${c}</p>`), '')
```